# Enable Symfony AppCache, but tag routes to be exempt?

Tags: php, symfony, http, caching, reverse-proxy

Reading the Symfony Reverse Proxy Cache docs such as [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/http_cache/form_csrf_caching.html) I have a need for this, but I'd like to just prevent the caching from happening on certain routes overall.

Perhaps an annotation or regex setting somewhere, just to say something like

```
/**
* @Route("/my/route", name="my_route", cachable=false)
*/
```

or

```
/**
* @Route("/my/route", name="my_route")
* @ProxyCache(false)
*/
```

Is there something like this, or a composer package that does this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FOSHttpCacheBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSHttpCacheBundle), it allows you a fine tuning of what should be cached or not. For example, a given [action](http://foshttpcachebundle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/headers.html).

Comment: Thank you I will check this out